# Center object's mesh around its pivot

Tags: interface

In Blender, after resizing a box - ie you could make it very flat like a square tile, the pivot point of the object will likely be outside. How do I move the mesh and/or the pivot so that the pivot will be located exactly in the center of the mesh?

Comment: Yes, indeed looks the same as my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>>*origin to geometry*. You can also use the 3D cursor as a pivot point, by hitting <kbd>.</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: It's strange. All of a sudden today when pressing Shitf-Ctrl-Alt, a "zoom" feature of OS X (don't think it's Blender) shows up and I'm unable to perform Origin to geometry.

Comment: I found out how to fix the above. It's an accessibility setting, I must have somehow had it turned on by mistake. System Preferences→Accessibility→Zoom, uncheck Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom